# Find sidebar.php in WP 3.9.2

Tags: sidebar

I have tried to find sidebar.php in WP but I cant find it.

Can anyone help me? I would like to remove achieve and META.

I have been looking for this php file sidebar for a very long time now.

Your sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your theme or setup as a sidebar on the Widgets page.

Comment: doesnt WP 3.9.2 have the same look on EVERY computer. I cant find the sidebar.php. And its not where you say it is. Can you be more specific?

Comment: sidebars are theme specific - what theme are you currently working with? review http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Existing_Widgets_in_Existing_Widget_Areas 
to change the file directly, review http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files

Comment: I found it by going to the FTP server.